# What is "content validity"?

Tags: self-study, validity

I'm a university student studying statistics by 'Discovering statistics using ibm spss 4th edition'

I don't understand what 'content-validity' means even though I read the explanation from the book again and again...

Comment: (+1) If you hover your cursor over the [tag:self-study] tag, a brief explanation will appear. Clicking on the tag will take you to a lengthier description of its purpose. As far as "content-validity" goes, its meaning is difficult to determine without the context. Perhaps you could supply an extended quotation? Based on extensive experience answering questions here, I can also affirm that any statistics book with "SPSS" in its title is likely to cause more problems than it solves--this one in particular. If you have any option at all, consider using another book for your studies.

Comment: In response to @Peter's request, the kurtosis question has specifically been asked at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172467.

Answer (score 0):

Content-validity is a measure of how well your variable(s) measure your desired construct (or value, attribute, proficiency, ability, skill, etc).  I think it is helpful if they give examples:

Some measurements can be validated quite easily, such as measuring height in centimetres.

Other measurements, such as emotions or quality of sleep are more difficult.  Is sleep only a matter of time slept? Or are there other factors to consider, such as length of REM sleep, consecutive sleep hours, etc.  Content-validation is often accomplished using domain expertise.
(good link: http://dissertation.laerd.com/content-validity.php)